# Create multiple tables based on json data in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a json object:

```
const dummyData = [
{group: "withoutHistory", view="pending", total=70},
{group: "withHistory", view="pending", total=10},
{group: "hold", view="security", total=17},
{group: "confirmed", view="verfication", total=11},
{group: "notConfirmed", view="verfication", total=15}
]
```

I want to create multiple datatables/grid based on the views.

this json object will create 3 datatables:

```
**table 1** for pending

group                           total
withoutHistory                   70
withHistory                      10

**table 2** for security

group                           total
hold                             17

**table 3** for verification

group                           total
confirmed                        11
notConfirmed                     15
```

How can I create 3 tables based on this json data?  Thanks in advance.  I tried to loop through the json data but I didn't get any luck. It would be great to have one data table as component and send data source based on view element of Json data.

Answer (score 1):

You above json contains = sign that is invalid. I have corrected and based on your input I have separated your data into three separate array below. You can execute code and check.

```js
var dummyData  =  [
{group: "withoutHistory", view:"pending", total:70},
{group: "withHistory", view:"pending", total:10},
{group: "hold", view:"security", total:17},
{group: "confirmed", view:"verfication", total:11},
{group: "notConfirmed", view:"verfication", total:15}
]
var separate={};
for(var row of dummyData) {
  if(separate.hasOwnProperty(row.view)){
   separate[row.view].push(row);
  } else {
   separate[row.view] = [row];
  }
}
console.log(separate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  How can I use this resulted json in the front end to create 3 data tables?

Comment: You can use like, separate.pending array and display data using ngFor. Read in detail here https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data